# Trying to send params to axios in get - react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm new here on the site, and new to React.
I built a function that works great in nodejs. There are rare cases where I want to run this function according to the parameters I send it to, so I try to send it the parameters but I think I can not, I try to print it - and I do not get a print of the parameters I want to send.

i run the function throw click at buttom in react:

```
 <Button onClick={() => {
        const result = [1,2,3,4,5,"test"];
        props.makeMatchVer2(result);
      }}>
        make match ver2
                    </Button>
```

the action I'm run in axios:

```
export const makeMatchVer2 = (data) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_DATA });
  axios
    .get('/kmeans', {
      params: {
        filterArray: data
      }
    })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: MAKE_MATCH,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: MAKE_MATCH,
        payload: []
      });
    });
};
```

the function I'm build in nodeJS:

```
exports.addUserKmeansMatch = (req, res) => {
  
  console.log("addUserKmeansMatch function start:");
  console.log(req.data);
  if(req.params)
  {
    console.log(req.params);
  }
  let userIndex = 0;
  let engineers = [];
  let engineersHandles = [];
  let engineerDetailsNumeric = {};

  db.collection("preferences").get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const engineerDetails = doc.data();

      if (engineerDetails.handle === req.user.handle) {
        engineersHandles.unshift(engineerDetails.handle);
        delete engineerDetails.handle;
        engineerDetailsNumeric = convertObjectWithStrToNumber(engineerDetails);
        engineers.unshift(engineerDetailsNumeric);
      }
      else {
        engineersHandles.push(engineerDetails.handle);
        delete engineerDetails.handle;
        engineerDetailsNumeric = convertObjectWithStrToNumber(engineerDetails);
        engineers.push(engineerDetailsNumeric);
      }
    });

    kmeans.clusterize(engineers, { k: 4, maxIterations: 5, debug: true }, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
      } else {
        const cluster = result.clusters;

        let foundedMatches = GetUserSerialGroup(userIndex, [...cluster], [...engineers]);
        let foundedMatchesHandle = GetUserSerialGroupHandle(userIndex, [...cluster], [...engineersHandles]);

        let totalTest = {
          foundedMatches: foundedMatches,
          foundedMatchesHandle: foundedMatchesHandle,
          cluster: cluster,
          engineersHandles: engineersHandles,
          engineers: engineers
        };
        let userMatchHandle = reduceUserMatchHandle(foundedMatchesHandle);
        userMatchHandle.handle = req.user.handle;

        db.doc(`/match/${req.user.handle}`)
          .set(userMatchHandle)
          .then(() => {
            return res.json({ message: "Details added successfully" });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
          });
      }
    })
  })


};
```

Through the button, I send parameters to the function, but I do not see their print, probably something does not work, but I do not know why, I'm new to it

Comment: Looks like `makeMatchVer2` is a function that returns a function (Possibly a [redux thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)?), so calling `makeMatchVer2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "test"])` won't make any axios calls.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I use redux-thunk.
I think I do not see the prints of the nodeJS in firebase, I do not understand why but.

Answer (score 0):

makeMatchVer2 is a thunk. You should call it with dispatch: `dispatch(props.makeMatchVer2(result))`

Comment: thank you for the help, I tried to add the dispatch, but it gets me an error: 'dispatch' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, I accidentally sent the wrong object, I have 2 objects with almost identical names, one array and the other an object. And I accidentally sent the object instead of the array, it's working right now, thank you.